little doubts about fubini theorems and so on
My professor wrote this :$f \in L^1(X \times Y) \Leftrightarrow \quad x \mapsto \int_y f_x \in L^1 \quad and / or \quad y \mapsto \int_x f^y \in L^1$
I think $\Rightarrow$ is ok and is a consequence of Fubini theorem . Even if I am not sure , bacause I would write $x \mapsto \int_X f_x \in L^1 a.e X$
for the $\Leftarrow$ I am lost
and I even don't know if it is true because GENERALLY mathematicians always show that $f \in L^1(X \times Y)$ using the modulus and NEVER that one of the 2 functions above  $x\mapsto \int_X f_x \in L^1$
why? I mean for me It looks simplier than working with modulus

The “or” version of the reverse implication is definitely false. For example, $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $Y = [-1, 1]$ both with Lebesgue measure and $f(x, y) = xy$.

“And” false: $e^{-(x-y)^2}$

@Eric so the $\Leftarrow$ is always false ?

Perhaps a clarification: does the RHS means $f_x \in L^1(Y)$ for a.e. $x$ and furthermore the function $x \mapsto \int_Y f_x$ is in $L^1(X)$? I don’t think @Eric ’s example satisfies the “furthermore” part.

@DavidGao is only what is written $x \mapsto \int_y f_x \in L^1$ not necessarely also  $f_x \in L^1$ Because in class said this is the theorem and nothing else

@DavidGao  tell me if I considered your counterexample in a proper way: $ \int_y f_x =0$ so the function $x \mapsto \int_y f_x \in L^1$ but $f$ is not in $L^1(X \times Y)$ because if I consider the positive part than is not integrable ?

@nathan That is a correct understanding.

@nathan The notation is not completely clear then. I’d suggest you just ask your professor for clarification.

@nathan Personally, I suspect your professor just miswrote. Or alternatively maybe they meant $f$ as being nonnegative.

@DavidGao i also think  the converse is true if $f$ is not negative  because I can use in the same way Fubini theorem . In this way I would use or statement  because the integral over the product is the same first $X$ and after $Y$ or $Y$ and than $X$ is it correct?
